# How to not require entry of a one to many or none field

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I have the following classes:

```
public class QuoteGeneral
{
    public int QuoteGeneralID { get; set; }
    public QuoteStatus Status { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateRecevied { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateDue { get; set; }

    public int? QuoteClassificationID { get; set; }
    public virtual QuoteClassification QuoteClassification { get; set; }

    public int? QuoteSalesRepID { get; set; }
    public virtual QuoteSalesRep QuoteSalesRep { get; set; }
}

public class QuoteClassification
{
    public int QuoteClassificationID { get; set; }
    public string Classification { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<QuoteGeneral> QuoteGenerals { get; set; }
}

public class QuoteSalesRep
{
    public int QuoteSalesRepID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public decimal CommisionPercentage { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<QuoteGeneral> QuoteGenerals { get; set; }

}
```

When I use scaffolding to create the controllers/views, it creates DropDownLists for QuoteClassificationID and QuoteSalesRepID. If I run the project and click on Create New for QuoteGeneral, those drop down list already contain values with no way of leaving them blank. How do I allow the user to not have to enter/select a value for QuoteClassificationID and QuoteSalesRepID?

Comment: Have you considered using ViewModels as an intermediary between the controller and the view? That way, you can bind your DDLs to corresponding properties on the ViewModel - you can then populate these properties using your own logic from the controller; and likewise insert using the "selected" (or not) values from the ViewModel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what your view look likes so I'm assuming you've got a QuoteClassification SelectList somewhere

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.QuoteClassificationID, QuoteClassificationSelectList, "")
```

That last "" parameter is what adds the empty value to the list.

It would help if you include you view code.  At least one of the DropDownListFor statements.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the manual method. Shortly after asking the question I figured out I could manually add the `""` to force a blank entry. However, shouldn't the question mark after the int in `public int? QuoteClassificationID { get; set; }` force that to happen automatically when scaffolding?